# Import AdSupport,social,account framework into Xcode 4.2 on Snow Leopard

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.2

I am using AddThis sdk for social sharing which internally required to add `Adsupport,Social and Account` framework.

But I am still using Snow Leopard OS due to older mac mini.

I have `xcode 4.2.`

I have tried to manually copy the all above framework from my friend's mac Lion OS machine,to my machine framework folder.

I have added all frameworks to my project but is not detecting.It simply showing like missing files error of all files of those new frameworks.

Can any one help me?Or

will not support these frameworks in leopard OS with xCode 4.2.?

Comment: you need to update your xcode for use that framework :)

Answer (score 0):

The framework you mentioned i.e. Social and AdSupport are present in the iOS 6.0, thats why they are not present in your project. For this you should implement your project in iOS 6.0 and keep the target as iOS 5.0 or as desired.

[check this Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12777226/add-social-and-adsupport-framework-in-ios5-and-ios-6-both)